# Looping Hue Animate

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm using cycles and have a texture that I want to animate by changing the hue so that it cycles through the rainbow. I know how to make keyframes of nodes, however I'm not sure how to make it seamless when the hue slider operates on a 0-1 scale. Would it just be a matter of changing the animation curves??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Maths node set to 'Modulo' to convert an input value into a repeating range; the output will vary between 0 and the value set on the second input. For example, with the following nodes :

[image: hue continuous]

Varying the 'Value' will produce Hue that varies between 0 and 1, then restarts back at 0. This will produce a continuous repeating range of hues as Value increases from 0 upwards (simply keyframe Value from 0 to, say, 5 to result in 5 repetitions of the range of hues : 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0).

---

As @RobinBetts pointed out, using the Modulo function can cause strange effects then using *negative* values as the Blender 'Modulo' function (as is the same for many programming languages) flips the output for negative input values. To correct this we can add a couple of additional Maths nodes :

For example, here's the usual output from the Modulo function :

[image: modulo]

Notice how the output flips in the centre as it crosses zero.

Adding Maths nodes to Add the Value, followed by a second Modulo corrects for this - by effectively shifting all values that are less than zero back to being positive :

[image: modulo - fixed]

Comment: I was trying this earlier this evening, and it seems to raise an anomaly, crossing zero. In Python, -0.3 mod 1 ==  0.7 mod 1, so you get a sawtooth, continuous down the number line. I doesn't seem to be so with the modulo math node? The results of -.3 and .7 are different?  I _think_ in the node, the sawtooth reflects about / rounds towards 0, where Python rounds toward -infinity. .. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828092/python-style-integer-division-modulus-in-c)

Comment: @RobinBetts It seems that this is implementation dependent - so different programming languages can potentially produce different results. The Python result that you mention follows the strict mathematical definition of negative module - ie, it's always positive and follows the same 'pattern' as for the positive side of zero. Some languages (eg, JavaScript, C) produce negative results for negative values - effectively `(-x) mod y` is equivalent to  `-(x mod y)`.

Comment: So in order to avoid  ..(1,0),(1,0).(1,0),(0,1),(0,1)..  @Toadhands  has to  stay one side of 0, I think...

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes - staying to positives would certainly avoid the problem. I presume from the question that won't be a problem since it's just some arbitrary value that's being animated. However, by adding a couple of additional maths nodes you can avoid the problem of negatives - see edit.

Comment: Cunning. I spent quite a time trying to figure out how to fix this in a snappy way...... I thought it probably wouldn't take you long.... Glad I didn't put my clumsy solution up :D... also quite important for procedural textures, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - very useful when using Object coordinates that can go negative. It’s something that’s caught me out in the past. Until you pointed it out I didn’t realise so many programming languages did it differently.

Comment: Rich, I reconstructed your nodes and played with settings. I got 15 different (very interesting) results as posted in Facebook group. I did over 10 more patterns before that. https://www.facebook.com/groups/Blender.Nodes/?multi_permalinks=2714073138633740&notif_id=1559358625505001&notif_t=feedback_reaction_generic

Comment: @Rich, All this time later, I ran into a hitch with your node implementation of  positive saw-tooth modulo. Because of the way the native modulo node  handles division by zero, `0 mod x` is evaluated as `-x`, outside the `[0.0 , x)` range. Now `floor` is available, probably better to use `x - (y * floor(x/y))`

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts - well spotted... that's a really interesting case.... and it actually explains some behaviour I've seen (but not understood) with some of my shaders when using Generated coordinates for some sides of the default cube (since they start at zero). I think your suggestion could work... but I'd be a bit concerned about the divide by 'y' - what happens as it approaches zero...? Could be rounding or precision errors. I think the original Modulo behaviour is definitely a bug since it's inconsistent at x=0 and think it's probably worth reporting. Shall I submit a bug or do you want to?

Comment: @RobinBetts I’ll raise it - it looks quite convincing to me. As an example, consider 0.00001 mod 10, -0.00001 mod 10, 0 mod 10 - all values very close to each other. Using the Node implementation you’ll get results of 0.00001 for the first, -0.00001 for the second and -10 for the third - wildly different but they should actually all be very close.

Comment: I’ve put together an example that visualises it quite convincingly (I’ll update the answer when I get chance).

Comment: [My demo](https://imgur.com/a/Gklxrnl), stripped down. Blend file  [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6578/).

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts. I've raised this as a bug at https://developer.blender.org/T69978, including an image that shows the discrepancy at x=0 quite clearly.

Comment: Excellent description. Yup, following that, it's a bug.

Comment: @RobinBetts Looks like the issue has already been resolved in Blender 2.81 - so it appears it was a long outstanding bug that's now fixed.

Comment: Okydoky, case closed. Apologies for taking us up a dead-end.. but we weren't to know....

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for pointing it out - and at least it prompted me to install the latest 2.81 :-) Looks like it’s a bug that’s been there for a long time so it’s good it’s resolved now.